# java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)

Tags: android

it is giving me very strange output.On my first input the map camera shows the toast msg "address not found" and on my second input it takes me to my first location...and by continuing this process i am given the exception stated above...any hints , helps ,links would be highly appreciated...thankx..`

```
public void geolocation(View v) throws IOException   {
         if (check_connection()==false)
         {
             alert_user();
         }
         hidesoftkeyboard(v);
         EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);
         location= et.getText().toString();
          gc = new Geocoder(this);
          new my_second_thread().execute();
         if (list == null )
         {
             Toast.makeText(this,"address not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return;

         }
         else if ( list.size() > 0)
         {
             Address add = list.get(0);
             String locality = add.getLocality();
             Toast.makeText(this,"moving..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            double latitude = add.getLatitude();
            double longitude = add.getLongitude();
            gotoloc(latitude, longitude, zoom);
            add_markers(latitude, longitude, locality);

         }

    }

//the above function uses asyntask which is:

    class my_second_thread extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Address>>{
        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... params) {
           try {
            return gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> result) {
            list = result;
        }

}``
```

Comment: change `else` to `else if (list.size() > 0 )`

Comment: possible here `list.get(0);` may be the problem. make sure `list` have some items.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i checked that but it is still giving me the same output..can u please check it again....thankx

Comment: @Rustam i have checked it several times.when i type my first address ,it dosent get it and when i type seond address it moves to first one i typed...plz tell me where is my logical error...thankx

Comment: post new code and new logcat error, i don't think that problem happened again

Comment: @shayanpourvatan this is the new code..this time it do not gives me out of bound exception but also not desired output...(it wont move on first location but on second location that i type it will move to the first loation..)..

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace...

Comment: @m0skit0 I think the OP said there was no more errors (thus no stacktrace), only incorrect behavior

Comment: @Joffrey The title is a part of a stacktrace...

Comment: @m0skit0 u r right but when i follwed shayan advice it is not giving me exception any more...it was working fine when i used the function without asyntask but after that it is not giving me desire output...so the logical error is offcourse caused my asynctask...plz check my logic...thankx

Comment: @FaisalAthar Time to learn to debug :)